# STS response WSFederationAuthenticationModule IsSignInResponse is always false

Tags: asp.net, adfs, federated-identity

I have tried to integrate Federated Authentication with my existsing Asp.Net 3.5 website using the code from http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2012/09/forms-authentication-revisited.html. The issue is fam.IsSignInResponse(request) is giving false even after getting valid response from the STS(AD FS). GetClaims() is slightly modified, as it's in a separate classlibrary. Same code is working in another test application. I am not sure where it's going wrong, please help me.
Please see the code below.

```
public List<ClaimEntity> GetClaims()
        {
            logger.Info("Started executing GetClaims()");
            List<ClaimEntity> claims = new List<ClaimEntity>();
            // sam is configured in web.config
            var sam = FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule;
            logger.Info("Declaring sam");
            // fam is not
            var fam = new WSFederationAuthenticationModule();
            logger.Info("Declaring fam");
            //fam.FederationConfiguration = FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration;
            fam.ServiceConfiguration = FederatedAuthentication.ServiceConfiguration;
            logger.Info("Assigning ServiceConfiguration to fam");
            var request = thisContext.Request;

            // is this the response from the STS
            if (!fam.IsSignInResponse(request))
            {
                // no
                logger.Info("fam.IsSignInResponse => No");
                // the STS
                fam.Issuer = _IssuerSTSSpec.Issuer;
                logger.Info("IssuerUrl= " + _IssuerSTSSpec.Issuer);
                // the return address
                fam.Realm = thisContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
                logger.Info("Assigning fam.Realm= " + thisContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
                logger.Info("Creating SignInRequest...");
                var req = fam.CreateSignInRequest(string.Empty, null, false);                
                logger.Info("Redirecting to the issuer...");
                logger.Info("Request to STS: "+ req.WriteQueryString().ToString());
                // go to STS
                thisContext.Response.Redirect(req.WriteQueryString());

            }
            else
            {
                // yes  
        -----------
        -----------

            }
            logger.Info("Returning the claims");
            return claims;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured it out.
This was an issue with the trust created in AD FS vs forms authentication.

In detail, EndpointReference in the meta data xml was just the domain name of the web application(SP), ie https://example.com. The site was receiving the AD FS response in the home page(Default.aspx), not in the page i configured, that was Login.aspx. When home page receives the response, it redirect to the login page as per the form authentication configuration not as sign in response, since WSFederationAuthenticationModule IsSignInResponse is false, the login page again redirects to the AD FS url. This was happening recursively.

I changed the EndpointReference to https://example.com/Login.aspx and it started working as expected.